# How to do decode linux RAW data

Tags: printers, network-printers

I am having a problem trying to extract the original contents of a text file that I am printing through localhost:9100, for Linux with a simple python server found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47738773/python-how-to-decode-a-raw-printer-output-from-localhost9100?noredirect=1#comment82438021_47738773). However in windows looking under the spool directory, the text is plain as day (this is not using anything apart from changing the generic printer to RAW and localhost:9100).

However, I need to be able to do this on Linux, I believe the encoding WinAnsiEncoding might be the problem. But I am not sure. The sections below show the output.

**test_text.txt**

Contains

> TEST101

**From Windows spool**

Contains

> D      8   t e s t _ t e x t   -   N o t e p a d   T e s t
>        Ñ   ÿ  O  Ω             R  †s   EMF              l 
>   `  X  “   (              54 çÖ P r i n t   t e s t     %
>   Ä%         ÄR   p     •ˇˇˇ
>   Ëär  Ö9È$ñ[  HÏô]   H   g   $8uˇ               òÏô]
>   H               lxˇ  ¿:„år  @ <çr          <ç            œ=uˇ
>   ì      …≥
>
> ```
>  πj=uˇ  ÄÒår  qÇ=uˇ  S   :   ¡±ˇdv     %                                               b         d        Äm
> ```
>
> T   Ñ   ¢  O  Ω   °     ﬂ{á@uPá@¢  O         L
>   ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ`   t e s t _ t e x t   <   <   <   <   <   <   <   <   <
>      ÿ  ≥  à  ¥  T   x   ÿ  ≥  {       ﬂ{á@uPá@ÿ  ≥     L 
>             ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇ\   T E S T 1 0 1   <   <   <   <   <   <   <   K
>             T   p   ¸  ¥  c        ﬂ{á@uPá@¸  ¥     L
>   ˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇX   P a g e   1 <   <   <   <   <   <

**From Linux**

Contains

> b'%PDF-1.5\n%\xb5\xed\xae\xfb\n3 0 obj\n<< /Length 4 0 R\n   /Filter
>   /FlateDecode\n>>\nstream\nx\x9c+\xe42P\x00\xc1\xa2t\x05\xfdD\x03\x85\xf4b.\xa7\x10.K\xb0\x90\xa5\x82\xa1\x85\x82\x85\xa1\x99\x9e\x89\x91\x81\x81\xb1\xb9BH.\x97~\x9a\xae\x81\xae\x81\x82\xa1BH\x1a\x97F\x88kp\x88\xa1\x81\xa1fH\x16\x97k\x08W
>   \x17\x00[\xe6\x0f\xf9\nendstream\nendobj\n4 0 obj\n   77\nendobj\n2 0
>   obj\n<<\n   /ExtGState <<\n      /a0 << /CA 1 /ca 1 >>\n   >>\n
>   /Font <<\n      /f-0-0 5 0 R\n   >>\n>>\nendobj\n6 0 obj\n<< /Type
>   /Page\n   /Parent 1 0 R\n   /MediaBox [ 0 0 595.275591 841.889764 ]\n 
>   /Contents 3 0 R\n   /Group <<\n      /Type /Group\n      /S
>   /Transparency\n      /I true\n      /CS /DeviceRGB\n   >>\n
>   /Resources 2 0 R\n>>\nendobj\n7 0 obj\n<< /Length 8 0 R\n   /Filter
>   /FlateDecode\n   /Length1
>   4532\n>>\nstream\nx\x9c\xedW}l[\xd5\x15?\xf7=\xfb\xf9+q^\xd2\xc48q\x13?\xe7\xd5\x8eS\xdbqj\xa7\t\xcdB\xf2\xea/\\x9c@\xbe\\xec\x98\x0c;\x8dC\xa0t\xcb\x96.JP\x19e\x08\xc8\xdc\x96fh\xd3\x04\x83Q\x89ih\x08\xad\xd7\x94\xa10\tVM\x08\xb1A\xa0\x7f\xa0i\x1a\x0c\xf5\x8f}t\x1bA\x15P*!\xb5\xde\xb9\xcfN\xd6\xf2\xa5\xfd1\xed\x8fi\xcf\xef\xdes\xce\xef\x9c{\xee\xb9\xf7\x1c\xdf\xf7\x1e\x10\x000\xc2a\xe0A\xdaw
>   7\xf7\x87\xbf=>\x07\xa0\xf9\x08\x80\x9b\xd8\xb7pP2\xddTw#\x80n\x18e\xcd\xcc\xdcm\x07\x16^\x8c\xbc\x0c``` \x18\x07\x10\xe4\xdb\xee\\\x9a\x89\xff\xec\xe7<zx\x06\xc7\xc4g\xf3\xb9\xe9\x0bB\xcb\x1f\x01j\x16\x11\xeb\x9eE@\xbb\x93\xe9j(\xca\xdbf\x0f\x1c\\4\xad\x92i\x94\xdfB\xd9z\xe7\xd7\xf7\xe5\x00L[Q~\x0f\xe5\xad\x07r\x8bs\xc2\x82\xe1I\x00Q\x8f\xb24\xf7\xcd\xfc\xdc\xc3\xfd\xfe\x9f\xa0\xec\x06
>   \x05\xe0
>   \x80\xf4\xd7\xdc\xfb\x18\xad\x0el\x8aI\xc3\x1bt\xa0\xd7\x12\rD``\xcd\xbfF\xc4\xdf\xad\x89\xef\xae\xed\xe8\x0c\xd6:j\xdb\xb0\x05\xc8J\xe0\xf2[\xdc\xfb\x97\xea\x02\\\xe1\xd2\x02z%\xd0\x86\xdd\x1a\xb7\x1f=HJ\r\xe1\xe7\x05\x8d\xc6\xa0\xe7\xb4K\xba\xdd\x1a\xf42\xb0\x1e
>   \xb5u\xbb\xfco\\zcG\'i\x90k\xf1\xb7\x93\xac==\xfa4\xb7?v\xe9m\xce\x19c>2\xd8\xbd\x8e>L\xd0\xad4\xebt<o\xac\xd6\x1a\xe61P\x8c\xb1J\xbf\xa4\xd5\x1a4Kd\xb7a\x89\xc5\xb5>\xb0\x8e\xfe\xd61\xb6\xc9\xf5\x80\xf8F\xc0\x1f\xf0\xab\x0168\x1a\x82\r2\xf6\x19\x92\xb9|\xf1\xdc9b\xc7\x19^\x8a\xbd\x1dC\xff=\xa5\x0f\xc9\x8b\xdc\x12\xec\x80\xdf+&\xaf\xd5\x0cC^\xb1\x1a\x86\xdaVK\xe7N\x19Uz\xfe\x94\x01\x86\xb61Z\xad\xd23\x0c\x97\x99\\\x03C6fW\x0bCM\xab\xa5\xb3\xa7\xea ```\xa8\x9e\xc9ez\x9e\xe1H\xcf>W#\xc2\xa0\xaa@\xef[\x10P\xfa\x911\x89\xe6\x1a\x184I\x06#\x0cr"\x9a\x127\x8ekh\xe0\x17\\xc1\x8e\x8e\xad\x0bP-Vs\xd5\x81\xb4\x9e\xe8\xdb\x1b\x1d\xa2\xdf\x0f\x87\xdac\x16K\xe3!1\x8a+\r\xf8Y\xab\xdd\x85\x1b8\xa9\xae7\xe8\x17\xdf\xc5nG\xa7\xe73WO\xa0{gW\x07\xd7\xd6\xc1\xef\xec\xea\x0e\x06Z\xb8kt.\x97\xdc*4\xd4#\xdb\xc27\xd4\x0br+\xaa{,\x96\xbf\x0f\x84\xac\xee@SK\x8f\xa7q&\xd3\xb8c\xbb\xc3\xd8T\x1f\xf3\xf8B[\x1c\xde&\xd7\x80\xaf\xf1\xc0\x8c\xa3\xd7\xd7jh\xac\xbf\xb1\xb7\xb3\xb3\xb9\xdd~\x8d\xb1\xaa\xc5\xdd\xed\x1c\xc9\xe8\x8cf]\xb4\xca\xea\xf35m\xb3YL\xa2\xe4\xed\xf3\x8c\xdcl0\x9b\x85\x88\xa9\x19\xd4ZH`\xf7<\xe6Q\x84\x90\xe2\xe2\xacU\x95\xf5\x12\t7\x15\xcb\xdc(h\x8f\xf0Fc]\xad\xd6\xf8\x90>\t\xa2h\xe2\xf7\xc2@0\xe8_\xdb(\x93\xe0\xa55q-P^\xe0\x96\xee\xee\x9e`m\xb0\xc1\xb13Xk\xe6u\x89`\xb6\xbd\xf7[\x97O=`\xb2;\xdd[\xc8?\xea\xaf\xf3_z;\x16#\xcf\x1a\x1b\xea\xeb\x046?\x0f\x1d\x98\xe7W0\xcf&\xb8\x06<\xf0\xf1\xf3\xedb\xb5\x19\x06\x9d\x95\xac8+\xe9\xb5Wd\xa4\xe7\x95z\x04l\xaa\x99\xc5*\xc2\x90E\xaa)\xe7W\xcd\xa7\xc8F
>   \x8a\xf4\x8c\x82\x99\x1c23\x1b\xb3\x88\x9c\x9e\xa9Z+\xb4E\xa5\xe7\x9e\xb35\xc3
>   \xac\x96N+m\xb6\xad0\xb8\x02d\x18\x8f\x82\x158\rg\xe1<\x08\xa0\x18\xaa\xe2p\xBxS\xe0\x05\xc5\xd6\x12\x17\x98\xad\x84\xa8
>   \xb4Z\x8f\xd6\xf9Z\x8fVy\x07x\xc2\x9f0\x10\x83\xa1\xa6\xedx\xc3\xcd\xcd\xc7kRj\xcd\xd7\xee\xf2O\xae\xb1*X\xc7\x12@\xc1\xe3\x99\\xf3L~\xc3\xf3\xd9Z
>   ,\xd5.\xb5\n,Z\xb5W\x93\xefrby\xc8\xadf\x8eUD0\xd0\xcf\x91.{c\x93$55\xda/\x7f\xb2?7u\xc7\x1dS\xb9\xfd$R\xb5\xb5\xa3\xb5\xb5ck\xd5\x06%\xbb\x9b\\xae\xa6&\xb7\xdb\xf9\xd8SO=\xc6Z0\x13q\xbb#\x99`\x85\x963\xcf\x03;\xf9\xaa@\xc3\xe1\xf9\x06-X\x01<\x98\xe1\x1e(\x911\x92#\x8b\xe4\xdb\xe4a\xee\x15\xee\x1d\xc9%uJ\xbd\xd23\x8e\xd6R\x89\x9dIp\x82\x8c\x92,\xea\xef\xae\xe8\xb7\xa0~\xd7\xa6\xfe\x8b/\x82s\xbcC\x1e%\x8f\x91\x1f\xe3\xefD\xe5\xf7\n\xfe^%\xaf~\xe9\xc8\xf2\xa5\x05\xcd\xbfa\xc5.\xeeKt\xe5U\xff\xff\xfa\x1f\xbe\xf04+_\xd5\xa5\x0f\x19!g\x00JX\xf4\xdc/T\xd4X\xfa\xb8\xf41>\xf1U\xcb\xd2\x07`F{3Z|@\xba\xb05rsd\x11QC\xe9"|\x02\x06\xc4/~\xee$\xa3j?\xaer\xf8@\x84^\x88c\x1fR\xf1QH\xc2<\\x87x\x18\xa58\xf6\x8b\x88\x8d#\x8d\xa9V\xa3\x90\xc5\xfeAD\xfa\x10\xe9V\xf98\xf2\xbe+\xfco\xff\xcf\xee\xc9\x7f\xef"\x8d\xa5\x8b\xca@*9>6:2|\xd3\x8dC\x83\x89\x1b\xf6\xc4\xaf\x8fE#\xe1\xd0ne\xa0\xff\xba\xbe\xaf\xf4\xee\xba\xb6\xa7{\xa7\xbf\xc3\xe7u\xbb\x9c\xdb\xe4V\xbb\xb5\xbeV\xac\xa96\x19\rz\x9d\xa0\xd5\xf0\x1c\x01oT\x8ee%\xea\xcaR\x8dK\x8e\xc7}L\x96s\x08\xe4\xae\x00\xb2TB(v\xb5\r\x95\xb2\xaa\x99t\xb5\xa5\x82\x963\x9f\xb2T\xca\x96\xca\xa6%\x11\xa5>\xe8\xf3y\xa5\xa8,\xd1\xb5\x88,\xad\x92\x89\x91\x14\xf2\xc7"rZ\xa2\xeb*?\xa4\xf2\x1a\x97*T\xa3\xe0p\xe0\x08)j\x9d\x8dH\x94d\xa5(\x8d-\xcc\x16\xa2\xd9\x08\xfa+\x9a\x8ca9\x9c7\xfa\xbcP4\x9a\x905!G\xdd\xf2\\x91\xb8\xfb\x89\xcap\xeeho\x91\x03}5\x9b\x96\xf2\xcehn\x9a\x0e\x8f\xa4\xa2\x11\x9b\xc3\x91V1\x08\xab\xbe\xa8\x10\xa6:\xd5\x97t;\x8b\x19\x8eHE\xef\xe9\xc2\xd1U\x11\xa6\xb2\x9e\xaaiy:wK\x8a\xf29\x1cT\xe0\xa3\x85\xc2\x83\xb4\xd6C\xdb\xe5\x08m\xbf\xebOV\r\x9ez\xe5H\x94zdt\x96\x18\xdd\x9c\x80P\xadS\x94\xa5\xc2\x05\xc0\xe0\xe5\xf5\xf7\xaeFr\x15Dp\x8a\x17\x80\xb1l\x89\x9b\xdb\x84\xfa\r\x1e06\x8c\x10\xd7\xe7p\xb0X\x8e\xac*0\x85\x02=<\x92*\xcb\x12L\xd9\x9e\x05\xc5\xefIS.\xcb4\xa774\rI\xa69\xbc\xa1\xd9\x1c\x9e\x95\x1d,U\xd1l\xe5^\x98\xb5\xd2\xc3S\x92\xcf\x8b\xbb\xaf\xdeN\xbcQ/Q\xde\x95\x9d\xda7\xcbh.*\x90#\x91\xf2\xbe\x8d\xa7\xa8\x12AF\xc9U\xd6\x1a-v\xfa\xd1>\x97\xc5E\xdc\xce\xb6a$E\xfd\xf2\x1c\xad\x97Ce\x03\x04$\x96\x83\xdb\xc7R\xea\x90\xca0Z\x1f\xa6\x90\xddW\x19E\xfd\xd1\x08\x8bK\x8a\x16\xb2\x91r\x80\xcc\x97<\x92z\x01\x82\xa5\xb3\xc5.\xc9v*\x08]\x90fqPK\x18\x93\xe2\x8a\x16R\xd33\xd4\x9e\xb5Mc}\xceH)\x9b\x83*i\xdc\xbe\xb4\x9c\xca\xa7Y\x96d\x91\xb6\x9f\xc5\xe9\x1c\xea\x8c\xea(\\xdb\xa7\xac7\x8c\xd9\xcauN\xbd\x94\xe2l|\x9ae\x0b\x01)\x86\x9d\x1c\xeaC\x85\x88\xe9RE\x96\xd1P\x9f\x94"6\xd80\xc3Y*\x16\x8c\xbb\xca\x0f\n\xbc3\x1cg*\x9e\r\r\xc7m\x8e\xb4\xa3|}IH\xb6JLZ\'\xd5*\xe1KD`3\xa6\xf2<_\x18Z\xd9\x9a\x05\xd4.E\xf3\x91+\x02\xbc\xca\xa9\xb6\x12`\xc5\xdb\xe7\xc7\xc9\xb1\xbd\xa8L\x8c#\xf4,\x9d\xf1\r\x15\xef\xc4\x7f.b\x1c\xbaQ!\x96E\xabDaXJ\xc9y9-c\r)\xc3)\xb66\xb6\xd7j~\x13crbd"\xa5f\xbbR%\xe3WIe\xfd\xb5\x9b\xba\nG\xb90\x16`\xccc\xdb\xc8\xa9*_\xaf\xca\x9bb\xfcS\xea=\x1bj\xa9\xa0\x97\x13c\x05\xe6Y\xae8\x04\xa9\xb0\x87\x02\x96\xac\x82\x7f\xcek\xeb\xba*\xff\xdf\x18\x1eor,\'K\xa2\x14+\xe4VK\x87\xa7\nEE)\xccE\xb3\xb3\xbd\xcc\x8f\xbcg\xba
>   \x8f\xa5\xfaljx\xa3\xa9\xbbmw\xb1\xe9\xea
>   A\x12\xe3!\x9f\x17\x0f\x9fPQ&\xcb#E\x85,\x8fM\xa4^\x10\xf1%oy<U\xe4H(\xcd\xaa\xdf:\x8b\x0b\xc4\xc3.*M\xb3\xcd9\x94\x9e-d\xd3\xac\xb4\xc1\x82\x1b\x897\xa1D\xee\x07\xca\xc9\xfdE\xc2\tU\xd4(\xe7C\xd4$\x87\x18>\xc0\xf0\x812.0\\\x87i!\x16\xe2\x83\xf2{\xd8\xeb\xaf\x8bo\xfd%pkM\xdf\x050\xf0\xe7\x18\xf2\x9b?\xbf\xf4\x1a\xa3\xbf\xfd\xe9M\xaf]~\xb9\xb4\x97{\x84\xefG\xd1\x80ou\xe577\xec\xf9\xfe\xd2^d>*eJ\x19\xee\x91\xcf\xbc\xd1\t\xe4#\x08`k\xc3\x96\xc1\xd6\x83-\x81\xad\xa3\xa2\x8f`[\xc6\x86\xf3q\xec\xbb\xfe\x0c\xfbvW\xbd\x08d\x1c\x9f\xdd_\xc3/c\x0e\xdf\x87\xfd\x90\xc6\xd7\xce\xa7t\'\xd9[\xa3b~\xe2\xc9\x93Or\xca\xe3M\x8e\xd8\x8f\x96\xb6\xdb\xd9w@\xd5\xa3Uu\xb1\x1f.\xc5\xed?\x98/\x03\xe3\xdfG\xe0\xe1\xf9-\xf6\xef\xcd\xc7\xed\xc7\xd1\xea!T\x1eE\xe5\x11\x94\xefEZ\xb8o\xbb\xfd\xbb\x0f\xc4\xed\xcb\xa8\xbb\x1fu\xf7\xa1\xedw\x10\xbf\x07\xf5\x8bH\x0f!~r\xe9WKo.\xf1\xca\x92]\x8e-
>   \xf6KB
>   L@iM\xce\x86oK\xce\x84\xf3\xc9\xe9p.\xb9/\x9cMN\x85oM~5<\x99\xbc%\x9cIN\x84\xd3I\xba\x8af7\x90\x9a<\xde\xf7\xe4\x8f\xe7\xf9N<\xa0s\x9d\xb9ln%Gsgs\xc2\xc9[\tL\x92\xce\xc9\xec\xe4\xca$\x9f\n\xefM\xde\x1cN&\xc7V\x86\x92\xa3+\x89\xe4\xc8\xca\r\xc9\xe1\x95=\xc9X&\x94\x8cfv\xe3\x13\x1c\xdd\x9d\xb2\x10-Y%+\x89U\xfe\xaf\xa3\t\xaa\x1f\xceP\xb2L\x9dc\xacWF&\xa8\xb0L!9\x91I\x15\ty(}\xff\xb1c\x10jN\xd0\xe6\xb1\x14=\xd1\x9cN\xd082\nc\x0e#\x03\xcdE\x0b\x84\xd2\x1e\x0fl|\xf7\xcc\x1f\x9c\xc7\xfb\xe0\xfc\xbf>\x84P7\xcf\xc8\x86\x11Q\x19&\xab\x00\xea\x0fZ\x01\xfe\t\x84\x8e\xc1\x17\nendstream\nendobj\n8
>   0 obj\n   2568\nendobj\n9 0 obj\n<< /Length 10 0 R\n   /Filter
>   /FlateDecode\n>>\nstream\nx\x9c]P\xcbn\xc3
>   \x10\xbc\xf3\x15{L\x0e\x118\x8eo\xc8R\x95^|H[\xd5\xed\x07`X\x1c\xa4\x1a\x10\xc6\x07\xff}\xd78J\xa5\x1e`g\x1f3;Z~\xed^;\xef2\xf0\x8f\x14t\x8f\x19\xac\xf3&\xe1\x1c\x96\xa4\x11\x06\x1c\x9dg\xd5\x19\x8c\xd3\xf9\x91\x95_O*2N\xe4~\x9d3N\x9d\xb7\x81I\t\xfc\x93\x9asN+\x1c^L\x18\xf0\xc8\x00\x80\xbf\'\x83\xc9\xf9\x11\x0e\xdf\xd7~/\xf5K\x8c?8\xa1\xcf
>   X\xdb\x82AKr7\x15\xdf\xd4\x84\xc0\x0b\xf9\xd4\x19\xea\xbb\xbc\x9e\x88\xf67\xf1\xb5F\x84s\xc9\xab\xdd\x92\x0e\x06\xe7\xa84&\xe5GdR\x88\x16\xa4\xb5-Co\xfe\xf5\x9a\x9d1X}W\x89\xc9\xe6B\x93BP`\xf2\xd2\x14L\x81\xea\xf5^\xaf\t\xd7U\xc1\x14\x08\x8b\x1d\x8b\xa2\xfdP\xd9\xb6l\xe7x\xda\xd7KJ\xe4\xbc\xdc\xacX\xde\xcc:\x8f\xcf\xb3\xc6\x107Vy\xbf9px\x10\nendstream\nendobj\n10
>   0 obj\n   245\nendobj\n11 0 obj\n<< /Type /FontDescriptor\n
>   /FontName /UKESOF+UbuntuMono-Regular\n   /FontFamily (Ubuntu Mono)\n
>   /Flags 32\n   /FontBBox [ -316 -170 665 830 ]\n   /ItalicAngle 0\n
>   /Ascent 830\n   /Descent -170\n   /CapHeight 830\n   /StemV 80\n
>   /StemH 80\n   /FontFile2 7 0 R\n>>\nendobj\n5 0 obj\n<< /Type /Font\n 
>   /Subtype /TrueType\n   /BaseFont /UKESOF+UbuntuMono-Regular\n
>   /FirstChar 32\n   /LastChar 84\n   /FontDescriptor 11 0 R\n
>   /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding\n   /Widths [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   0 500 500 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 500 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 500 500 ]\n    /ToUnicode 9 0 R\n>>\nendobj\n1 0 obj\n<< /Type
>   /Pages\n   /Kids [ 6 0 R ]\n   /Count 1\n>>\nendobj\n12 0 obj\n<<
>   /Creator (cairo 1.14.6 (http://cairographics.org))\n   /Producer
>   (cairo 1.14.6 (http://cairographics.org))\n>>\nendobj\n13 0 obj\n<<
>   /Type /Catalog\n   /Pages 1 0 R\n>>\nendobj\nxref\n0 14\n0000000000
>   65535 f \n0000004169 00000 n \n0000000190 00000 n \n0000000015 00000 n
>   \n0000000169 00000 n \n0000003833 00000 n \n0000000299 00000 n
>   \n0000000527 00000 n \n0000003189 00000 n \n0000003212 00000 n
>   \n0000003535 00000 n \n0000003558 00000 n \n0000004234 00000 n
>   \n0000004362 00000 n \ntrailer\n<< /Size 14\n   /Root 13 0 R\n   /Info
>   12 0 R\n>>\nstartxref\n4415\n%%EOF\n'

**Screenshots of linux printer setup**
[image]
[image]

Comment: The Linux one is clearly PDF/PS data, is it written like that in a text file or are you viewing it in a non-hex editor that took on it to convert all non-printable bytes to the `\x<value>` notation?

Comment: @zwer It is written to a text file. Do you think it is an issue or setting up the printer properties or an issue of collecting the data from the socket?

Comment: If you're collecting the data from a socket via Python, you'll be getting a byte string (or `bytes` in Python 3.x) - make sure you decode it to whatever codec it was encoded in (I'd assume `ascii`) before writing it down to a file.